# Почему этот код с потоками не работает?

Tags: discord.py

Я пишу бота , который считывает построчно информацию из файла и отсылает в дс. Я решил использовать потоки,чтобы цикл while True: не мешал работе бота. К сожалению после команды >startLogging поток не запускается. Что тут не так?
P.S. Я новичок в discord.py.
P.S. Я хз,но табуляция сбилась.
Вот мой код:

```
async def logging(ctx):  
    print("Функция logging запущена")
    try:   
        with open("colorcode.txt") as readcolor:
            colorcode = readcolor.read()        
            color = discord.Colour.from_str(colorcode)

        with open(pathtologs, "r", -1, "utf-8") as f:
            while True:
                for line in f:
                    # await ctx.send(line)
                    print(line, end="")                embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Лог с сервера", description=line, color=color)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    except:
        print("В функции logging ошибка")



@bot.command()
async def startLogging(ctx):
    print(type(ctx))
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=logging, args=(ctx,))    
    print("0")
    t1.start()    
    print("1")
```

Comment: Вероятно, потому что вы пытаетесь **синхронно** запустить в отдельном потоке **асинхронную функцию**. Попробуйте использовать специальный метод из модуля `asyncio`: `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(logging(ctx), bot.loop)`